# Ionic 1 modal renders broken

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I am having a problem when rendering a modal using $ionicModal using Ionic 1.
The modal opens, but it appears broken as in the image.

[image]

I don't have a clue of what may be the cause of the problem. The app was running on Android 6.0, Moto G, third generation. Is it associated to crosswalk plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the Ionic1 has been upgraded.

Try to do the same using Ionic 2 Ionic@beta. That might help.

When you upgrade your code to Ionic 2, you might have to edit some of your present code. Just take care.

If you still have problem, then start pondering more into the code.

Comment: Upgrading to Ionic 2 is the only option?

Comment: I'm not sure, But that will be the best option!